# Floating point arithmetic and comparison causing undesirable output

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, floating-point

Consider the Pandas DataFrame `df1`:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"Name":["Kevin","Peter","James","Jose","Matthew","Pattrick","Alexander"],"Number":[1,2,3,4,5,6,7],"Total":[495.2,432.5,'-',395.5,485.8,415,418.7],"Average_old":[86.57,83.97,'-',96.59,84.67,83.10,83.84],"Grade_old":['A','A','A','A+','A','A','A'],"Total_old":[432.8,419.8,'-',482.9,423.3,415,418.7]})
```

I calculated the `Average` and `Grade` with the following formula

```
df1["Average"] = df1["Total"].apply(lambda x: x/5 + 0.1 if x != "-" else "-")
df1["Grade"] = df1["Average"].apply((lambda x:'A+' if x!='-' and x>90 else 'A'))
```

So df1 becomes

df1

```
        Name  Number  Total  Average_old Grade_old  Total_old  Average Grade
0      Kevin       1  495.2        86.57         A      432.8    99.14    A+
1      Peter       2  432.5        83.97         A      419.8    86.60     A
2      James       3      -            -         A          -        -     A
3       Jose       4  395.5        96.59        A+      482.9    79.20     A
4    Matthew       5  485.8        84.67         A      423.3    97.26    A+
5   Pattrick       6  415.0        83.10         A      415.0    83.10     A
6  Alexander       7  418.7        83.84         A      418.7    83.84     A
```

`df1` has `Total, Total_old, Grade, Grade_old, Average, Average_old`. I am trying to check if any value of Total is modified with respect to `Total_old`, any value of `Grade` is modified with respect to `Grade_old` or any value of `Average` is modified with respect to `Average_old`.   I am trying to create a new `Dataframe` `dfmod` that would give all the modified values of   df1 with the following code

```
dfmod = pd.DataFrame()
columns =["Total","Average","Grade"]   
for col in columns:      
   dfmod = pd.concat([dfmod,df1[["Name","Number",col + '_old']][df1[col].ne(df1[col +'_old'])].dropna()],sort=False)

dfmod.rename(columns={col + '_old':col},inplace=True)           
dfmod = dfmod.groupby('Name',as_index = False,sort = False).first()
```

And got the output as

`dfmod`

```
        Name  Number  Total  Average Grade
0      Kevin       1  432.8    86.57     A
1      Peter       2  419.8    83.97  None
2       Jose       4  482.9    96.59    A+
3    Matthew       5  423.3    84.67     A
4  Alexander       7    NaN    83.84  None
```

Here no values of Pattrick was modified when comparing Total with Total_old, Average with Average_old, and Grade with Grade_old so Pattrick's entry was correctly dropped.

However if you observe `Alexander's` `Average` even though the `Total`, `Average` and `Grade` are same as `Total_old,Average_old,Grade_old`  respectively , the modified value dataframe `dfmod` has the `Average` value wrongly added as a modified value. The reason why it happened is because floating point arithmetic wont work like integer arithmetic in programming languages as mentioned in the link below. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/floating-point-error-in-python/

so I tried to implement `np.isclose` function as:

```
for col in columns:  
     if col is 'Grade':
          dfmod = pd.concat([dfmod,df1[["Name","Number",col + '_old']][df1[col].ne(df1[col +'_old'])].dropna()],sort=False)
       continue

    dfmod = pd.concat([dfmod,df1[["Name","Number",col + '_old']][~np.isclose(df1[col],df1[col+'_old'])].dropna()],sort=False)
```

But it throws the error message as

```
  `Exception has occurred: TypeError ufunc 'isfinite' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''`
```

The error seems to be because of the '-' character in the data how can I fix this issue, please do help, I am stuck at this issue for a while and tried all the resources I could get.

Expected output:

```
        Name  Number  Total  Average Grade
0      Kevin       1  432.8    86.57     A
1      Peter       2  419.8    83.97     A
3       Jose       4  482.9    96.59    A+
4    Matthew       5  423.3    84.67     A
```

It should omit the values for James,Pattrick and Alexander as they don't have any change for Total - Total_old, Average - Average_old, Grade - Grade_old

Comment: It's kind of unclear what is it that you want to do. You want to find the difference between a dataframe and another dataframe that is basically a copy of the first? Also, the pre-processing code snippets are irrelevant if not distracting.

Also, how are you so positive that "is because floating point arithmetic wont work like integer arithmetic in programming languages"? It seems as an invalid deduction. 

You need to state more clearly where is your point A and where is your desired point B. Regardless of the code which is a bit confusing.

Comment: if i'm not mistaken, i believe your expected output is incorrect. `Peter` should have `A` as their `Grade`

Comment: @ThanosNatsikas I am 100% positive that it is floating point arithmetic issue because I purposely made this example from a larger dataset to have that issue here. I think Derek's solution is great and that was what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell, the `"-"` character is unnecessary – you can replace it with `None` in the columns where they show up, then make those columns numerical. This will make your preprocessing steps much cleaner, and avoid unnecessary conditional statements where we need to check whether certain values are `"-"`.

```
df1 = df1.replace("-",None).astype({"Total":float, "Average_old":float, "Total_old":float})
```

Then you don't have to use `.apply` or check for whether a particular element is `"-"` when creating the new columns `Average` and `Grade`:

```
df1["Average"] = df1["Total"]/5 + 0.1
df1["Grade"] = ["A+" if x>90 else "A" for x in df1["Average"]]
```

Then you can use `np.isclose` in your condition, drop any rows containing null, select the columns with `"_old"`, and rename the columns:

```
condition = ~(np.isclose(df1['Average'], df1['Average_old']) & np.isclose(df1['Total'], df1['Total_old']) & (df1['Grade_old'] == df1['Grade']))
cols = ['Name','Number'] + [col for col in df1.columns if "_old" in col]
df1.loc[condition, cols].dropna().rename(columns={'Total_old':'Total','Average_old':'Average','Grade_old':'Grade'})
```

Result:

```
      Name  Number  Total  Average Grade
0    Kevin       1  432.8    86.57     A
1    Peter       2  419.8    83.97     A
3     Jose       4  482.9    96.59    A+
4  Matthew       5  423.3    84.67     A
```

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look if this is what you are looking for.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


def compute_grade(new_average, old_grade):
    try:
        grade = 'A+' if float(new_average) > 90 else 'A'
    except:
        grade = old_grade
    return grade

df1 = pd.DataFrame({"Name":["Kevin","Peter","James","Jose","Matthew","Pattrick","Alexander"],"Number":[1,2,3,4,5,6,7],"Total":[495.2,432.5,'-',395.5,485.8,415,418.7],"Average_old":[86.57,83.97,'-',96.59,84.67,83.10,83.84],"Grade_old":['A','A','A','A+','A','A','A'],"Total_old":[432.8,419.8,'-',482.9,423.3,415,418.7]})
df1["Average"] = df1["Total"].apply(lambda x: round((x/5) + 0.1, 2) if x != "-" else "-")
df1["Grade"] = df1.apply((lambda x: compute_grade(x['Average'], x['Grade_old'])), axis=1)

print(df1)

# import pdb; pdb.set_trace()

dfmod = df1[(df1['Total'] != df1['Total_old']) | (df1['Average'] != df1['Average_old']) | (df1['Grade'] != df1['Grade_old'])]

print(dfmod)
```

Output:

```
        Name  Number  Total Average_old Grade_old Total_old Average Grade
0      Kevin       1  495.2       86.57         A     432.8   99.14    A+
1      Peter       2  432.5       83.97         A     419.8    86.6     A
2      James       3      -           -         A         -       -     A
3       Jose       4  395.5       96.59        A+     482.9    79.2     A
4    Matthew       5  485.8       84.67         A     423.3   97.26    A+
5   Pattrick       6    415        83.1         A       415    83.1     A
6  Alexander       7  418.7       83.84         A     418.7   83.84     A
      Name  Number  Total Average_old Grade_old Total_old Average Grade
0    Kevin       1  495.2       86.57         A     432.8   99.14    A+
1    Peter       2  432.5       83.97         A     419.8    86.6     A
3     Jose       4  395.5       96.59        A+     482.9    79.2     A
4  Matthew       5  485.8       84.67         A     423.3   97.26    A+
```

Rounding off the average we compute to 2 decimals was the key here.

Also when computing the Grade if we encounter non numeric value like '-', i was returning Grade_old.